# "endOnTick" and "stopOnTick" seems to be ignored in highcharts scatter graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to trim in extra edges from the xAxis .
I am using end on tick and start on tick to achieve that but somehow it seems that highcharts is ignoring that.

[image]

Here is the [**(fiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2PHR/1/)

**Options Set**

```
 xAxis: [{
                       gridLineWidth: 2,
                       lineColor: '#000',
                       tickColor: '#000',
                       gridLineDashStyle:'ShortDash',
                       categories:xAxisCategories,
                       gridLineColor:'#000',
                       tickmarkPlacement:'on', 
                       endOnTick: true,
                       startOnTick: true,

                       labels: {
                              rotation: -45,
                              align: 'right',
                                 style: {
                                     fontSize: '13px',
                                     fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                         title: {
                                 text: null
                          }        

                    }],

                       labels: {
                                enabled: false
                               },
                         title: {
                                 text: null
                          }        

                    }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `startOnTick`. Anyway, that works exactly as should - note, you are using categories, that means plotting area is divided for categories equally ([docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes)). One tick = one category = one part of plotting area (for example width = 20px).

You have two options:

- don't use categorized axis (quite a lot of questions on SO are mentioning this - search for start/endOnTick or min/maxPadding with categories)
- set start/endOnTick to false,  min to (-0.5), max to (categories.length-0.5) and should work (-0.5 etc. may be different a little).

Comment: Thanks Your second alternate worked for me . But can you expain briefly, how it works ?

Comment: Each category is full number (0,1,2,3 ... n). In your case you want to start and end chart in the start/end of category, which is +/-0.5, and n+/-0.5.

Comment: Pawel .. I am working on a graph that will plot the graph based on certain search criteria .I noticed that my search return only two columns and in that case I if use min :.5 max:1.5 it is showing 3 columns .I have no idea what is going on

Comment: Try to set `minRange: 1`, it should resolve issue. If not, could you crete demo? :)